# Using Taylor expansion to prove equality involving central difference operator

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

> Use Taylor expansion to show that for $u \in C^4([0,1]) $ $$ max |\partial^+\partial^-u(x) - u''(x)| = \mathcal{O}(h^2)$$ For $x \in [0,1]$ and where the second order derivative $u''$ can be approximated by the **central difference operator** defined by $$\partial^+\partial^-u(x) = \frac{u(x+h) - 2u(x) + u(x-h)}{h^2} \approx u''(x)$$

I know what the Taylor expansion of $u$ around $x+h$ looks like, but I don't know how to evaluate $u''(x)$ other than setting it equal to the approximation $\partial^+\partial^-u(x)$ which makes the left side equal $0$.

Comment: Did you try to approximate $u(x+h)$ and $u(x-h)$ with their taylor series at $h=0$?

Comment: $$u(x+h) = u(x) +  hu'(x) \frac{h^2}{2!}u''(x) + ... + \frac{h^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}u^{(k-1)}(x) + \mathcal{O}(h^k)$$ So choosing $h = 0$ gives me a zero numerator unless Im misinterpreting something?